AWSIMのAutowareで2D Goal Pose を押しても自動運転が開始されない
AWSIM で autoware を起動し、2D Goal Pose でルート指定してみましたが、自動運転が開始されません。
どうすれば自動運転が開始されますでしょうか？
ご回答よろしくお願いします。

目的地をクリックしていたため、動かないことがわかりました。
目的地をクリック後、ドラックすることで自動運転を開始できました。
